# China version of Baota mandatory binding cell phone number solution

Tags: linux

Currently the latest version is 8.0.2, which requires account binding, which is very troublesome and there is no way to remove it.
Versions after 7.4.5 (excluding 7.4.5) require mandatory cell phone number binding.
Version 7.4.2 has a pma vulnerability.
Versions before 7.2.0 are not recommended because the code has been changed too much and can't be used properly after downgrading.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to downgrade to before 7.4.5：

Demo: version 8.0.2 --> 7.4.0

```
（1）、Installing curl dependencies
yum install curl
（2）、Download baota offline package
curl -L https://github.com/weiwang3056/baota_release/blob/main/LinuxPanel/LinuxPanel-7.4.0.zip\?raw\=true > LinuxPanel-7.4.0.zip
（3）、Unzip
unzip LinuxPanel-*
（4）、Switch to the downgrade package directory
cd panel
（5）、Execute the script
bash update.sh
（6）、Delete the downgrade package
cd .. && rm -f LinuxPanel-*.zip && rm -rf panel
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5hYm.jpg)